# definition of a type doesn’t work in agda

Tags: proof, agda, dependent-type

This definition of modular arithmetic doesn’t compile in agda :

```
data mod (n : nat): n → Set where
    zeroM : mod n
    S : mod n → mod n
    equMod : { x : nat} → (x ≡ n) → (x ≡ zeroM)
```

Error: `nat should be a sort, but isn’t`

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write n -> Set you need n to be a type but it is a natural number. I guess you just want to write `data mod (n : nat) : Set` which means that `mod : nat -> Set`.